# Is there a modern monitor that works with original amigas?

Tags: display, amiga

I realise that I'll need a scandoubler, but that will still mean a monitor that can sync to a 31kHz horizontal signal. Is there anyone actually using a currently-available LCD monitor in such a way? Would you recommend it? I'm keen to use a flat panel screen so I can keep the space requirement down, and to use a monitor because tvs are licensed in the uk.

Comment: TV's are lisenced as long as they're being used to display television.  
You can use a TV for a monitor for a games console or computer and not have to pay the license.  
From the TV licensing website:   
You need to be covered by a valid TV Licence if you watch or record TV as it's being broadcast.

Comment: @Joe in principle you're correct, and a TV used only "for playing video games" does not need a licence. However in practice the licensing organisation will treat a TV with an RF modulator as being used to watch live TV, and it will be up to the jury to decide whether that was indeed the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may not be what you're looking for, what I've done is plug the RF video from the Amiga into a Dell LCD monitor that has a standard composite video RCA input. ( It's an older 24" LCD monitor from Dell that isn't sold anymore, but this is it: http://goo.gl/DzWd. Of course there are now many multi-input monitors on the market, but not so many with composite video inputs.)

A really nice feature of this monitor is the picture-in-picture mode: the video from the Amiga can be placed in any corner of the screen. This works out well, since that small size matches (roughly) the resolution from the Amiga anyway. You can have the video take up the entire display, of course, if you love big blocky pixels. :)

Anyway, for me, this has been a good one monitor solution for using my PC and Amiga at the same  time.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 My brother has that monitor. I was impressed with the range of inputs it had. Remember that only the A1200 onwards had a built-in RF output, IIRC. My A500 only had a B&W composite output, as well as the RGB port. Didn't you mean colour composite output, anyway? RF would require an analogue tuner in the monitor, and would result in worse picture quality, wouldn't it?

Comment: There's a secret about RF output: if set to channel 3, it's the same as the color composite video output. The other way around: color composite video is simply RF video at channel 3.

What we used to do is make adapters out of a standard RCA connector and a standard television cable connector. We could then connect a machine to a standard TV (tuned to channel 3) without needing one of those game switcher boxes.

As for the video quality, that will depend on your cables and the monitor. Many of the modern TVs do a good job of cleaning up the analog signal. (... and sorry for the slow reply!)

Comment: @paradroid, I believe my old A600 has an RF output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need [something like this](http://www.ambery.com/rgbcgatovgac.html).  It's not cheap though, but it should help in finding something that does the same thing, but cheaper.

[More info here.](http://www.amiga.org/forums/showthread.php?t=38672)

Comment: that _is_ a scandoubler.

Comment: @Graham: Oh sorry, I seemed to have misread your question.  Googling suggests that scandoublers are the same as the de-interlacer 'flickerfixers' that I so wanted when I had an A500, so that I could use hi-res mode in Deluxe Paint without getting a headache (oh that takes me back).  I'm sure getting an original vintage one of those would be a lot cheaper, albeit difficult to source.

Comment: many scandoublers are also flicker-fixers. They don't actually de-interlace the image, they interpolate between the two adjacent lines so that the difference is less jarring.